# Can I remote desktop into Windows 7 from Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I'm using Windows XP at this moment at my home and business. I want to upgrade the OS at home, but not thinking of doing so immediately for my business for continuity reasons.

Now I connect to my home computer from time to time from the office - is it possible to connect to the terminal services of the home computer even if I upgrade the home computer to Windows 7?

Regards

Comment: I was just browsing my past questions and this came up - I confirm that it can be done, and I am using it right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can, but you'd better install [Remote Desktop Connection 7.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084) for XP SP3, [released](http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2009/10/28/announcing-the-availability-of-remote-desktop-connection-7-0-for-windows-xp-sp3-windows-vista-sp1-and-windows-vista-sp2.aspx) October 28, 2009.

See this article for details:
[Remote Desktop Connection 7 for Windows 7, Windows XP & Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2009/08/21/remote-desktop-connection-7-for-windows-7-windows-xp-windows-vista.aspx)

> This article discusses the Remote
>   Desktop Connection (RDC) 7.0 client
>   update that enables you to use the new
>   Remote Desktop Services features.
>   These features are introduced in
>   Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008
>   R2. These features are available for
>   computers that are running Windows XP
>   Service Pack 3 (SP3), Windows Vista
>   Service Pack 1 (SP1), and Windows
>   Vista Service Pack 2 (SP2).
>
> The RDC 7.0 client can be used to
>   connect to legacy terminal servers or
>   to remote desktops as before. However,
>   the new features that are mentioned in
>   this article are available only when
>   the client connects to a remote
>   computer that is running Windows 7 or
>   Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: We now also have Remote Desktop Connection 8.

Comment: it doesn't seem to have an update for Win XP though.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're running the latest version of Remote Desktop Connection (Terminal Services) on your Windows XP desktop (which is probable if you're up-to-date with security patches), then I don't see why it *wouldn't* work.

I haven't used Windows 7 yet, but had used RDP to connect to Vista and 2008 from XP.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on which version of Windows 7 you upgrade to but that was also the case with XP.

You need a Professional, Business, Enterprise or Ultimate version of Windows to do this.

So if you're upgrading from XP Professional to Windows 7 Business at home you'll be fine.

Comment: Note that Windows 7 had no Business version. Vista did. The 'Business' version of windows 7 is win 7 professional =) (and I know i'm nitpicking :p)